# What is the upward speed needed for a body to float near Earth's surface?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, speed

I want to know the velocity that a body needs to **i.e** literally *float* near Earth's surface assuming gravitational acceleration is 9.8 m/s² everywhere on the planet and the body is 1m away in altitude. What is the upward velocity needed to keep it orbiting in that altitude?

Comment: no such velocity exists

Comment: Floating implies staying over one point on the Earth’s surface. Is that what you’re talking about?

Comment: @G.Smith Yaaah!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_orbit

Comment: You can only “float” high above the Earth’s surface, at an altitude of about 22,236 miles.

Comment: Near the surface you would orbit in about 90 minutes, so you wouldn’t float over one point.

Comment: @G.Smith It doesn't actually matter, I just meant staying on the same **altitude** *on/near* the **surface** of Earth assuming gravity is the same everywhere as I've pointed above and even assuming the Earth is the perfect circle

Comment: Well then what is your limit on "near"?

Comment: So do you just mean an orbit 1m above the surface, as compared to floating?

Comment: You're asking what is the vertical speed of an object that is not moving vertically? By definition, it is zero.

Answer (score 2):

As I can understand from the question you are asking if there exists such an upward  velocity for which the object trains afloat at the same height? The answer then is no. The reason being that from any frame (as for here the earth) if an object posses some velocity then motion takes place (the very definition of velocity is dependent on motion!) ,and an absence of it does makes things thrown upward to look afloat . So when you give the object an upward velocity of then it must move upward (for the time till velocity becomes zero) howsoever large be the downward acceleration. Rather for floating you should ask if there is any way to make object to be at rest, then answer would be to apply some force to balance downward force and make the object to remain at rest. And yes it does happen all the time while you are sitting, sleeping etc.(by virtue of the normal reaction) I and hence you are currently [floating](https://youtu.be/yE8rkG9Dw4s).

---

**Edit**

Seeing your  comments on the question I would say the object is must to have a sideways (horizontal)  velocity rather than upward to stay in a given orbit of radius $R+h$(after it was placed in that orbit). The value of such velocity is given by $v=\sqrt {\frac {GM_{earth}}{R+h}}$ neglecting the air resistance.